# DropDown box for UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Can anyone let me know how to set a drop down box for UITextField with few name suggestions.

How can i do this????

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this for iPhone or iPad? They both have their differences in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity you can basically use just a Uipickerview+Textfield.

But if you want something like in below picture

[image]

I suggest you to follow this [tutorial](http://www.dalmob.org/2011/03/01/alternative-autocomplete-uitextfield/)