# Is it possible to implement 'auto complete' feature with ios keyboard?

Tags: ios

I'm wondering if it's possible to implement auto complete feature with ios keyboard - just like google does. Has anyone seen someone actually has done that before?

Comment: everything is possible. some things are more probable than others.

Comment: I assume you're talking about something other than the built-in autocompletion? Sure, that's possible; you'll want to disable the built-in autocomplete and then run your autocomplete logic whenever the value of a text field changes (or whenever a key press is detected).

Comment: Thanks guys! If one of you post it as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be auto complete drop down box.

When user `(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` call your logic and put your possible words into a `nsmutablearrray` and in a `popoverview` that contains `tableview` display that array, keep conituniue updating your array via your  detection methods and  if user `didselectrow`  put that label into `uitextfield`.

[DropDown box for UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202584/dropdown-box-for-uitextfield/11203099#11203099)